# AttributeError: module 'flask.app' has no attribute 'route'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have `autocomplete` function as a separate file - autocomplete.py. The autocomplete is being imported into **init**.py as follows:

```
from xyzapp.autocomplete import autocomplete
```

The line that throws error in autocomplete.py is the following:

```
@app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
```

The structure of the application is using blueprints and looks as follows:

```
appcontainer
     |
     |--run.py
     |      
     |
     |--xyzapp
          |--__init__.py
          |--autocomplete.py
          |--blueprint_folder_1
          |--blueprint_folder_2
          |--static
```

The whole error message looks like this:

```
 @app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
 AttributeError: module 'flask.app' has no attribute 'route'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

The autocomplete.py looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, app, Blueprint, jsonify

@app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    database='backbone_test'
    db=client[database]
    all_names=list(db.ids.find({},{"current_name":1,"_id":0}))
    return json.dumps(all_names)
```

The `__init__.py` file looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint, jsonify, session
import jinja2

class MyApp(Flask):
  def __init__(self):
    Flask.__init__(self, __name__)
    self.jinja_loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader([self.jinja_loader,jinja2.PrefixLoader({}, delimiter = ".")])
    def create_global_jinja_loader(self):
        return self.jinja_loader

    def register_blueprint(self, bp):
        Flask.register_blueprint(self, bp)
        self.jinja_loader.loaders[1].mapping[bp.name] = bp.jinja_loader

app = MyApp()

from xyzapp.autocomplete import autocomplete
from xyzapp.blueprint_folder_1.some_file import bp_1

app.register_blueprint(bp_1)
```

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you had a function underneath, after all, `@app` is a *function* decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `autocomplete.py`, it looks like you're importing `app` from `Flask` and not from your `__init__.py` file. Try importing from `__init__.py` instead.

Comment: for me a had a 'from flask import *' in my xyz, which pulls in app from flask. change app in the __init__ to myapp and it it should work

Answer (score 2):

import Flask first, the initiate your app

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: As you can see I am importing Flask and initiating the app. Still does not work

Comment: your code in this line : from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, app, Blueprint, jsonify 
you import app from flask, try to import it form __init__,   use this ( from . import app)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is a bit of a long shot, I'm not familiar with this way of running a Flask app, but it seems you create your own instance of the Flask class called MyApp and initialise it under the variable app.

I'm not 100% and may be completely wrong, but I think your problem lies in the `__init__` of `MyApp`

Answer (score -1):

Did you import Flask to your.py? Double check and make the addition of missing.

Comment: Yes, I have the following line in autocomplete.py: `from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, app, Blueprint, jsonify`

Comment: It's not a answer. It could be a comment.